# Unable to create Headless Chrome Instance with ChromeDriver and NodeJS

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, chai, google-chrome-headless

I am using NodeJS Selenium, Mocha and Chai to run test automation. I have spent several hours trying to get Chrome to run "headless" I use the function below to create a driver instance. When Chrome opens it is neither headless not maximized. Tested on both Windows with Chrome 76 and OSX with Chrome 74.

```
export async function getDriver() {

let options = new chrome.Options();
options.addArguments("--window-size=1024,768");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--headless");

var driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(options)
    .build();

return driver;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

do you try

```
const options = new chromeDriver.Options();
options.setChromeBinaryPath(CHROME_BIN_PATH); 
options.addArguments( 'headless', 'disable-gpu');
```

or just

```
let chromeOptions = { 
  'args': ['--headless', '--disable-gpu'] };
chromeCapabilities.set('chromeOptions', chromeOptions);
const driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities).build()
```